# Getting visual studio 2015 to work with Silverlight 5.0 OOB with RIA services

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-2015, silverlight-oob

I have a Silverlight 5.0 OOB application that works in Visual Studio 2010 to 2013. But I cannot get it to work in 2015. I've installed all of the same tools, etc, that required in the earlier versions. But no joy! Any one else have any luck? Or suggestions?
Thx

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I did to get my Silverlight 5 project working in Visual Studio 2015 RC:

Make sure you have [WCF RIA Services V1.0 SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28357) installed.  Reboot your machine after install.

1. Open properties page of Silverlight project
2. Unlink server project by selecting "No Project Set" option under WCF RIA    Services Link found on the Silverlight tab of properties page
3. Recompile (get lots of errors)
4. Re-link server project
5. Recompile (no errors)
6. Run project
7. Clear browser cache. Important!

Comment: Hello CardiacTwinky, unfortunately, that didn't work for me. Although it did change the number of errors and warnings I received upon compile, the 2nd time.

Comment: This worked for me. Actually my project was already working but Intellisense was broken since moving to 2015. After doing this, everything is back to normal.